# Taking care of perineum

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana, meditation-body

How can one take care of the [perineum](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perineum)

Does anyone have any knowledge about this part of the body being affected by excessive sitting in meditation. I have had medical help, removal of cysts, haemorrhoids and general stiffness over my course of meditative life.

Is this a normal problem with meditators and if yes how can one take care of this?

About me:
I am male, late 20s(fairly young to be having problems in that region?), sit cross legged (no lotus or half lotus), use a simple block, have had a history of stomach ailments since 12 (appendicitis, liver repair, bad digestive system), currently simple wholesome diet with no meat, eggs, do not drink/smoke.

Comment: Traditionally, Buddhism concerns itself with the state of the mind, rather than the body. That said, because there is a great affinity between mind and body, there is naturally an affinity between Buddhism and Yoga. While I'm far from being even an intermediate-level student of yoga, from my cursory knowledge of its principles it sounds like you have what they call "circulation problem" in your lower chakras. What my Yoga teacher recommends in such cases are exercises designed to improve energy circulation in the lower half of the body.

Comment: Here are some that come to mind (CHECK WITH YOUR DOCTOR FIRST BEFORE DOING ANY OF THIS!): 1) Tapping the lower abdomen with your fists left right left right, for 10 minutes at a time, not as strong as to hurt yourself, but strong enough to relieve any habitual tension barriers you might have. 2) Pushing the muscles of the lower abdomen out, 100-200 times. 3) Tapping your feet against each other, 1000 times.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the case:

- you can use a stool / chair or stadium seat
- you can use orthopaedic cushions to added comfort
- if sitting is a problem you can use another poster like lying down (don't use a cosy or luxurious bed as you will soon fall asleep. A hard surface may be best using a Yoga mat perhaps laying beaded seat cushion on top even if this causes you to fall asleep.)

Also when meditating try to keep your attention a bit longer in this region looking at the arising and passing away of sensation equanimously. Don't think of any healing or removing discomfort. Just keep your attention on the sensations. If this is Karmic, reducing your mental reaction for sensation resulting from karma means you will not be adding fuel to the karma prolonging it's results. If you react with any thing, like disappointment if any issue pops up, being happy when something does not pop up, etc. You are adding fuel to prolonging the ailment.

Comment: Option three: one can do the daily sits lying down?

Comment: Yes you can. But try using an orthopaedic cushion 1st.

Comment: Then a meditation stool, https://www.google.com/search?q=meditation+seat&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=uIwhVObcKc2F8gWaxYHwCw&ved=0CDAQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=653

Comment: Thank you Suminda. +1 for karmic relations. Dint think of it that way. Probably was reacting to the pain too much.

Comment: See: http://www.creativecrash.com/system/photos/000/266/527/266527/big/Medit_Chair_03.jpg?1355408150

Comment: One could do more active energizing exercises that could help recharge the body like yoga or Qi Gong. Walking meditation is an important exercise. Some schools just keep counting the breath while you go through daily life. Maybe the body is not adapted for long sitting. There are many ways ways including the exercise Hakuin suggested for meditator's sickness.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much consider adding walking meditation to your practice, both to potentially help your lower body issues and perhaps strengthen them at the same time. It is also a great tool for building concentration before doing sitting meditation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your cushion or wooden block is slightly slope downward. It'll give multiple benefits: increase blood circulation in the lower body, creates a naturally lean-forward posture that straighten the back without tensing the muscles, and relieve some pressure off your buttock and that perineal region. Some images to illustrate [here](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=979&q=side+meditation+posture&oq=side+meditation+posture&gs_l=img.3...524.3629.0.3765.23.11.0.9.0.0.209.1110.0j7j1.8.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..16.7.991.8D6ujGFP8jY)